# How to access Docker Desktop - minikube cluster from local machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

I installed docker and minikube through `Docker for Windows Installer.exe`. And this installed Docker Desktop 2.1.0.1.
[image]

Docker Version -

```
PS C:\myk8syamls> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        74b1e89
 Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:17:08 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       74b1e89
  Built:            Thu Jul 25 21:17:52 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

k8s version -

```
PS C:\myk8syamls> kubectl.exe version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**After I have created k8s services, I am not able to access them through my local machine.**

```
PS C:\myk8syamls> kubectl.exe get svc
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                       101d
nginx-clusterip-svc   ClusterIP   10.96.214.171   <none>        80/TCP                        26m
nginx-nodeport-svc    NodePort    10.101.9.117    <none>        80:30007/TCP,8081:30008/TCP   26m
postgres              NodePort    10.103.103.87   <none>        5432:32345/TCP                101d
```

I have tried - accessing nodeport service, **nginx-nodeport-svc** by hitting
10.101.9.117:30007 and 10.101.9.117:80  - did not work

and

I have tried - accessing the clusterip service, **nginx-clusterip-svc** by hitting
10.96.214.171:80                        - did not work

**How can I access these service from local machine??** This is quite critical for me to resolve, so any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit - following answer from @rriovall**
i did this -

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --type=NodePort --name=nginx-nodeport-expose-svc
```

and on querying -

```
PS C:\myk8syamls> kubectl.exe get svc nginx-nodeport-expose-svc
NAME                        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-nodeport-expose-svc   NodePort   10.107.212.76   <none>        80:30501/TCP   42s
```

Still there is no external IP and accessing `http://10.107.212.76:30501/` still does not work

or

```
PS C:\myk8syamls> kubectl.exe get nodes -owide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    master   102d   v1.14.3   192.168.65.3   <none>        Docker Desktop   4.9.184-linuxkit   docker://19.3.1
```

accessing `http://192.168.65.3:30501/` does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose the nginx cluster as an external service.

```
$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --target-port=80 \
--type=LoadBalancer

service "nginx" exposed
```

It may take several minutes to see the value of EXTERNAL_IP.

You can then visit http://EXTERNAL_IP/ to see the server being served through network load balancing.

Comment: that worked - localhost:80 and there is nginx.  ++1. Can you explain the concept behind this. Why nodeport did not work and loadbalancer worked.

Comment: if you liked the Q. please upvote so others find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Load Balancer:** This is the default method for many Kubernetes installations in the cloud, and it works great. It supports multiple protocols and multiple ports per service. But by default it uses an IP for every service, and that IP is configured to have its own load balancer configured in the cloud. These add costs and overhead that is overkill for essentially every cluster with multiple services, which is almost every cluster these days.

**NodePort:**  Is an open port on every worker node in the cluster that has a pod for that service. When traffic is received on that open port, it directs it to a specific port on the ClusterIP for the service it is representing. In a single-node cluster this is very straight forward. In a multi-node cluster the internal routing can get more complicated. In that case you might want to introduce an external load balancer so you can spread traffic out across all the nodes and be able to handle failures a bit easier.

In your case this would works too, you would need to create a service object that exposes the deployment:

`kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=nginx-nodeport-svc`

For more details check out this [public documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: i have added my observation to question, could you please review.